# How to pass complete value through parseint () method

Tags: javascript

i am working with parseInt() as it only allow to pass value before decimcal place how i could pass the whole value i need to add the value in the textboxes .this below is code for the display of result after getting value from three different textbox using javascripting

```
  function getText6(){
      var in32=document.getElementById('in3').value;<value from textbox1>
      var in332=document.getElementById('in33').value;<value from textbox2>
      var in3332=document.getElementById('in333').value;<value from textbox3>
      var in123=parseInt(in32)+parseInt(in332)+parseInt(in3332); 
      document.getElementById('in123').value=in123.toFixed(2);
   }
```

now when in textbox in123 value come only take two digits before decimal plce.
like 34.56+138.00+964.80=1136.00 it take only 34+138+964=1136 i want that it take whole term and ans =1137.36
kindly help me for this result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). The latter strips away any decimal places since integers do not have them.

Answer (score 0):

use [parseFloat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) instead of [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

```
var in123=parseFloat(in32)+parseFloat(in332)+parseFloat(in3332);
```